# How to scan for another device through Bluetooth- Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm developing Xamarin application using Visual Studio 2019. I have to connect to another device through Bluetooth and send some data and receive acknowledgement back. Tried these two samples out

1. https://github.com/msthrax/BLEApp

   and
2. https://github.com/didourebai/BLEPluginDemo.

But didn't help me **while scanning for nearby Bluetooth devices**, since the below codes are not giving expected result respectively..

1.

```
listView_DeviceList.ItemsSource = CrossBluetooth.Adaptor.GetListOfDiscoveredDevices();
```

and

2.

```
adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
{
    deviceList.Add(a.Device);
};
```

Both Bluetooth and location turned on in my devices. Can anyone let me know the possibilities of problem here. I don't have any build errors in both of the above samples. Whereas, I have one surprise also. Below line is giving proper result, which is of no use for me currently.

```
listView_PairedDeviceList.ItemsSource = CrossBluetooth.Adaptor.GetPairedDevices();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **enabling the Location Permission** for the app(earlier, I turned on Device Location, but we should **allow the app to get device location**), all my above problems are solved out.